# SQL server Openquery equivalent to PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-copy

Is there query equivalent to sql server's openquery or openrowset to use in postgresql to query from excel or csv ?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html, or http://pgoledb.com/  ?

Comment: Copy command worked for me thank you

Comment: You can also use a foreign data wrapper to read the file directly without the need to import it

Answer (score 2):

You can use PostgreSQL's [**COPY**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html)

As per doc:

> COPY moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system
>   files. COPY TO copies the contents of a table to a file, while COPY
>   FROM copies data from a file to a table (appending the data to
>   whatever is in the table already). COPY TO can also copy the results
>   of a SELECT query

[***COPY***](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-copy/info) works like this:

Importing a table from CSV

Assuming you already have a table in place with the right columns, the command is as follows

```
COPY tblemployee FROM '~/empsource.csv'  DELIMITERS  ','  CSV;
```

Exporting a CSV from a table.

```
COPY (select * from tblemployee) TO '~/exp_tblemployee.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

Its important to mention here that generally if your data is in unicode or need strict Encoding, then Always set client_encoding before running any of the above mentioned commands.

To set CLIENT_ENCODING parameter in PostgreSQL

```
set client_encoding to 'UTF8'
```

or

```
set client_encoding to 'latin1'
```

Another thing to guard against is nulls, while exporting , if some fields are null then PostgreSQL will add '`/N`' to represent a null field, this is fine but may cause issues if you are trying to import that data in say SQL server.

A quick fix is modify the export command by specifying what would you prefer as a null placeholder in exported CSV

```
COPY (select * from tblemployee ) TO '~/exp_tblemployee.csv' DELIMITERS ',' NULL as E'';
```

Another common requirement is import or export with the header.

Import CSV to table with Header for columns present in first row of csv file.

```
COPY tblemployee FROM '~/empsource.csv'  DELIMITERS  ','  CSV HEADER
```

Export a table to CSV with Headers present in the first row.

```
COPY (select * from tblemployee) TO '~/exp_tblemployee.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER
```